# CSS issue with a table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have what should be a simple issue: On my newest rendition of http://www.derekbeck.com/1775 the "Recent Updates" line is a table cell spanning three cells. (The three cells of this table are the left side, a spacer in the middle, and the right side.) The line you see is a border-bottom set by CSS. I want more spacing below that line, before the next row which shows the first of the recent posts.

I tried doing it by setting that table row with a margin-bottom value, but nothing happens. I did the same for the table cell containing "Recent Updates", but still nothing. padding-bottom works but simply increases the spacing between "Recent Updates" and the line. I want the spacing AFTER the line, before the next table row.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please present your layout and core problem in http://jsfiddle.com . We can then easily spot the problem.

Comment: Ugh! Don't use tables for layot.

Comment: How would you lay this out using divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the dotted border on the cell, put it on the "Recent Updates" div, then increase the size of the table cell by setting `height: ##px` and make it have `vertical-align: top;` (or use `padding-bottom` on the cell).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a blank table row after the "Recent Updates" row as shown below:

```
<tr class="recentrow">
<td colspan="3" class="titlecell"><div align="center">Recent Updates</div></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

You can increase the spacing by setting `height: ##px` for the blank row.

Comment: Same as last idea basically: an option, but not elegant. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at your site and did a little bit change in your CSS by using Firebug in my browser:

```css
td.titlecell {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #AAAAAA;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your fix works in firefox, and by the way, I think it did nothing in Chrome for example.